# Как выровнять блок при масштабировании?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при резиновой верстке позиционировать блок поиска? При масштабировании съезжает.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://asterial.ru/uploads/header.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  max-width: 2560px;
  height: 275px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  max-width: 230px;
  height: 76px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 17.7%;
}

.search {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  width: 13%;
  height: 30px;
  left: 16.5%;
  top: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 header">
      <div class="row">
        <a href="#" class="col-lg-6 logo"></a>
        <input class="col-lg-6 search" type="text" placeholder="введите текст">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Куда ж он съезжает? Он просто уменьшается вместе со всем хэдером

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://asterial.ru/uploads/header.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 110px;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(https://asterial.ru/uploads/header.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 275px;
}
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACoCAMAAABt9SM9AAAAgVBMVEX///8EgksAfUEAgEgAez4Af0WUwarR591hpoSSw6v3+/kDiFMAfkOZxrAAez292Mqx0cFusJAtkmPI4NTx+PWAuZ1Rn3m218er0L50s5Xa6uOIvaPn8+4ai1kAhk/L4tdMnXUAdjOhy7c3lWg2kGNAm3Bbo39mq4kikWDg7ugAcy78BsErAAAKfUlEQVR4nO2ceXuyOhPGQ0JKwYgVsHUB17cu5/t/wBfIAoGw1EfR1rn/Oed6GGv8mUwmMxMRAoFAIBAIBAKBQCAQCAQCgUAgEAgEAoFAIBAIBAKBQCAQCAQCgUAgEAgEAt1b7vejR/B79OXbs0eP4bfIocSy548exe9QHFDLIpbz6HH8Cn0yKxU9eI8eyC/QyrZy4cWjR/L8mviWkD959FieXTEhEhaxokeP5sm1pZYSOz16NM+tsW+V5G8ePZ5nVqyxskjw6AE9sz6pBsuyx48e0dByegdMX7bOyiKjV/Pxq2lPQ+9MKrAs/GpnxLfdqp/huDqxsvAhvu/gnk1v2O/leqKkNrFeb2q9Ycvf97Ab4zqr1Gu91tRKYVn2R6eZcWK93IaYwbL8ry6zufRYRP/P+aWyDzksgsMOs28ZY31zTAdBy+7E/JeUw7IIbc/mLUXwTrZjns/ar/k/0ONA43wKcVgWIcs2qxkTE2m+z+2xcxRTzX8lFy9gpRvbpdnIE+49jdn5rog3X+J1dp+t9K9IwrLouXmOOGIV0hOSsBS/V6qLKVgWPTQe9aQRnkhYTixjiVdahwUsizVWIQ5qFQpYxFVx1yuVxUqwLNawpCJhQz9VJF/kl19pPyzDsvCn0SYULgvvDccesh54xA+UBsuy3002EhBzTGdEvzXo+FPSYVm2qR54omIOeSZYPU6Wf0UVWJZtSG+dS1FCCZZwW7Rv+vD3qwrLst2ajaSSuXIFi8hjIjkMP+oHqQarnnaJpQkbl2D5k7nYGF8nFV+HVYucHJVQTrdDCcufq02StByU/pYMsKrprbDIvtsf/CCdZ1dlHZG9TLXVBMvaaemtcg2McEeFs6XqrbnTwi+T0zLCItpkmZdNBJ/8eUDk4ryVvCjcj93V234SN6ZgvTizccf7MBo6TWuElYZUpWTgvm7CM6tiO2RZtHE5vht1zLCuDA+PtcqQF84O2LdxKtu3g+mXYePwJovAlzb4sJgMyssMyyJJEZcbCjs5LJkRZFkg6/jUqNz/He36A7zVBxKNA5uVqiKE+smqsnXEbqLbMD9wB9yLG2BZNFGpFwWLabAWsk+EZs1HDqv9iVx5kv5I6w+ofg7dJ7hWPyJ4vSqh8NyRwcYejQebXU2wLBrIccplSOeqjSaFtVBuPw9W/w3W5ds2ltqIXaSNnKDRZqh24BKs0VobDA08HZaPvnxhgZ2C1Q1gfWGDASeRqK/MjCr/U2ygnFoBiySOpY2HiQYsGTr4EQqpsDiX2HTDOrXDcnclOpQyzKh8HwVr5pdtGE5tSoP1ezZs3A7WCDm6T2Db3GQiYaU+35Gp9/LHLvssgnXtyrBIycHbW8VKcSCMJtvF6m013SY49+QS1qKwsa3gOHPd2TEgxXD9QbouyrA8FDKNFs7TWzKCz/siDVtjnnYQsEgSTnTFBSySTEuSB/a9KnbbycyRqy4KF2usYCmeBB/2cov0luODwtWvveWmsFLvodGyMw5L8WnsiRkWm5VgGXsnBSxqSsRu5HKiViUKiGfpUsthfUlWONBPC948UQf7rqL6DVSBhT70NqzsTlMkYWWRej2fxc8+18KKAtkI8Fk/jzsHO4MVy7eyF7WgKprK4/wAyY8qLLTX22yzZOCZFjOogIW3ooSfp0qvhTWTxVqj0/He15G8AtNU0JU91Oz+ScgarEoDd+YMonX+YfXkn3+SWYc8nL8SlmyiaLyVd4rQZifesSFAkF8vvnv2ow5L3c8R2u1RPMo+LTmjAla6/UhPkrdJXAlLPGm9gSCqloYULtIGfP+inAGWFtNkXD7QZZTv40XBAqcjXwk+ubO4DlbMJw1JWk4sG4GipU9A3Pxg964zmWChqT63/Alysui+KIVlCWZVp85z8NfBckUqsW0nm/K/jFvysU7Jqd5TRljopNEiNESbdEfKonHZGJI6X+F285j0Sli8bkS3LQMUDZqs9c4efwMS3PlIbYaFjlo4laW3Joxk35yAlU6FTalO3RyU5rmLqQhKD+Un6eK9+N0TKxQTq3WJbbiRfed12ADL22pnPTJapv48mwEFLPlKOz/zq+OOrem/PIic0tpDf7eUQV16zuocYEdnk8ddwr37gRtgpW+v0aKjGM3/S/1wAUtGkzR/WcNB2tdglZV54wXvuWwNkPgKwx0nZfGX7nytrwlWGlprnzBLBu7T2aBgLaXL2ubmV8HiV6famwd57rrr4ixvRLy302qEheJEpxVEaPVRwJIBF+ZT/ypYfPG0uiyPT2Da4Y02HNb6UbBEcFV8uoOHSjPrW3b+8Y9xFSwOorUNR2yG647+wqWonTwMFlrqycC8xCBDh6X02Qm3VbCIJg5rYXiYbW88cvDbKtrxj2Dhx8FKCei0jgqWI8J35XkVrEBTosEaBedcSapRMbPaUujyHkxHi4AIS+kDYaFQT29h2a3Mwv/JVSg+qYyzRsjTlD8UsNI4TX8inHdbRdvjb4Q7ahIhbvoIt1Q7LDTx9WTgSlQvVOQk+40KWAYVsHTxQgZ+axsgP/d1tfnu+0Rj/6wOWNXUKU2EsaQnt/2rYLk9PiJ/bftpB6F32sfqX9UFS+90qIoox3sVLJHdx23em79/a15CebZ7X7vqhGW676tUfJW9YFXD8KjI9zRK7HPtt/xEMpze+QJDN6xSqaoOS/ndq2DJRFTrJnbozkx4PWxuoR6wqsnAQqXc5HWwRENA628miRG2TS3hKu5+6aoPLDRtoFW609kHVn25eeKmht1y9ItFfqf5l4IuvO/g/vWdXrAqyUA1sbaFxXWw0Bv/w2TdFHRuIvnqxryyJ67Z3v+3APrBqiQD6xOrHdasEZY3kneozAfEcB2hSGYZGwoS28G6pnvCqiQD+VddHnwvWIbcnCoRrU0rcW5ndUNZnMNbA47oMNw10Z6wUPRdo6Vleq+FhU7yKq09q6KITz6fLvI6O0tqRL9G8pn5ktZN1RdW+g1W8iz6FnY1rCLJiEduOU5ariwm1lYsk0UEv2uV1PAou7YGubrQG1Y1GUj04EhmHUYfuuaZ526DhZYqbUbw+rjfXOI4voRvW95QtM4ZbNT9Rsq+x5usldmLN+43o+qlQ3T/9YdV9GfkqhTTVYrGNlQsWmGhcg8dxcwajUYWk72AHBaaFEdUgtn6fDgka1b+t0EuLvwAFrqU0lvVaLmx8y/zMu2w0HKtz9nydyJgoZBSzUQzogP9yOxPYKGlak0k1WNYK6xVO6w0UmpqGCVUuqL40HRGJfb3QJfafwSr8B21/FIvWM2b+3htfD2lpUBzRY02zGo7h99UP4OFJnxusdr14EZYWeDaDQvFC6va5E4YO2rLa3kiNRtMp8NdSnvbyVZZm/TJyebJQJLU5r2zw0bld6Zm/OGutWB8WQU2Vl3KFNvJouaJlrPE12yC2ZA3tEO3UK8XZD8OxeqVvnjlGpXfKJmI/+/YsryNewyon4oln6vQGDh5oXs85zY0OLqbZ/9FqrHf3Fb27/Ki+LKM2+97ZTaXDptn0Wr76BGAQCAQCAQCgUAgEAgEAoFAIBAIBAKBQCAQCAQCgUAgEAgEAoFAIBAIBAKBbqb/A7h1mdwEPvelAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .logo {
  width: 200px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px; 
}
}
.search {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 40px;
  left: 120px;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .search {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  top: 150px;
  left: -80px;
  text-align: center;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<a href="#" class="logo"></a>
<input class="search" type="text" placeholder="введите текст">
 </div>
```

Не очень понятно как жить при % уменьшении. Намного проще сделать некую градацию. К примеру на маленьких экранах выглядит одно, на чуть побольше по-другому, а на больших еще изменения. Так будет в 100 раз понятнее клиенту, чем % уменьшение всего и вся. Вот сделал пример, при котором на 500рх меняется положение и размер объектов.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас разметка неправильная.

Стоит попробовать так:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://asterial.ru/uploads/header.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  max-width: 2560px;
  height: 275px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 230px;
  height: 76px;
  
  margin: 10px 0 0 17.7%;
}

.search {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  max-width: 230px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px 0 0 16.5%;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <a href="#" class=" logo"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
        <input class=" search" type="text" placeholder="введите текст">
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В bootstrap идет обертка `.container-flui`d дальше для колонок `.row` и внутри колонки `.col-` (при чем колонки для каждого разрешения свои, у вас `col-lg` это для десктопов, на мобильных эти колонки будут перестраиваться друг под дружкой).

А вообще лучше ознакомьтесь с [bootstrap](http://bootstrap-3.ru/index.php). Есть уже [4-ая версия](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/).